# Should ids be mapped to the implementation type

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, domain-model, data-modeling, strong-typing

This is a question of model design, and hopefully some architecture nerds have strong opinions on this. I've been developing one that I will post in an answer.

Typically, in every codebase I've ever seen, if your model has an integer id, it is typed as an `int` and if it has a guid id it is a `Guid`. Is this really correct? Is this leaky abstraction? Is it a leaky abstraction worth keeping?

Comment: Your question could be a better one.  I see where you're going with the answer, but questions need to stand on their own merit, and this one is "primarily opinion-based" (you even say so in your question).

Comment: It is, but as the FAQ says, some subjective questions are alright so long as they're constructive. This is questioning the wisdom of a common practice which seems to me of benefit to the community at large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using native types (`int`, `Guid`, etc.) instead of types which express the intent (`Price`, `ProductIdentifier`, etc.) has **two drawbacks**:

1. The type change is **cascaded all over the code base**, making it particularly painful.

   For instance, switching from `smallint` (`short`) to `uniqueidentifier` (`Guid`) is not only painful at database level (how do you transform production data from auto-incremented fields to randomly generated UIDs?), but also at code level. You must go through the entire code base and replace `short` by `Guid`, eventually dealing with **compile errors** or even **runtime errors** (in a case of a dynamic language or when Reflection is used).
2. The **type-related methods are spread through the code base** instead of being constrained within a single class. This creates a **risk of code duplication**.

   When you have `ProductIdentifier`, you can easily locate `CheckIfValueInRange` method: obviously, it is in `ProductIdentifier` class and only there.

   When you have `int` as product identifier, you may *guess* that `CheckIfValueInRange` is in data access layer, but then it's up to you to locate it. Under pressure, some programmers may be reluctant spending time searching for the method, and write their own checker:

   ```
   if (this.Id <= 0 || this.Id > 100000)
   {
       throw new Exception("The product ID is invalid.");
   }
   ```

   which may unfortunately differ from another implementation which is more conform to the spec:

   ```
   const int MAX_ID = 100000;
   if (this.Id < 0 || this.Id > MAX_ID)
   {
       throw new OutsideRangeException("The identifier is outside the allowed range.");
   }
   ```

   leading to refactoring/maintenance nightmare, which could easily be avoided if one were using `ProductId` class.

**Do identifiers change their type often?**

Actually, they are. A developer decides to use `smallint` for a small website; the website becomes hugely popular and once the limit of 32,767 values reached, the type should be changed. Another developer uses `uniqueidentifier`, and later it appears that there are no benefits for this type in the actual context, but having an auto-incremented, ordered value would be nice.

This makes identifiers a good candidate for using a custom type instead of a native one.

**Do identifiers have business logic?**

Aside range checking (see above), there are many cases where it makes sense to link the business logic to the identifier itself:

- Generation of a new ID,
- Checking of the existence of an ID,
- Checking if the ID belongs to a specific group (such as ID 1 to 10000 is group A, and IDs higher than 10000 are group B),
- etc.

Note that by removing the leaky abstraction of an ORM through the usage of a custom type, you're also creating a new leaky abstraction. Imagine you want to order something by ID. If `ProductId` corresponds to an auto-incremented field, it makes sense. If `ProductId` corresponds to a GUID, ordering doesn't make sense and you should be searching for a different criteria, like `Product.CreatedTimeUtc`.

Answer (score 3):

So lately I've been thinking that semantically the id is any unique identifier; the fact that it happens to be in the integer or the guid format is an implementation detail and exposing the fact in the type is a leaky abstraction.

Thinking about it, exposing it as a string or a dedicated `Identifier` type has some advantages, it makes things easier to mock, repeat, or switch to ordered identifiers. Of course, the database should be whatever makes it preformant, but that is another implementation detail.

My intuition is that a dedicated `Identifier` type is the way to go, and if your ORM doesn't support that, a string seems a second best option.

Comment: What ORM doesn't support genuine ID fields?  Seems like a non-starter to me.  What do you mean by "a dedicated identifier type?" One that is automatically generated by the database?

Comment: My understanding is that the `Identifier` type would sit in the application and would act as an abstraction of the DB's identifiers.